# Как передать переменную окружения для nodejs в docker при docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor

Цель: создать образ приложения на meteorjs

при вызове команды docker build, происходит сборка, согласно Dockerfile, но в какой то момент происходит ошибка

"FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory"

Нашел, что проблема может быть, как в ограничении по ресурсам машины, так и в исчерпании памяти самой nodejs

Вариант с ограничением отпал, так как пробовал на нескольких машинах и свободные ресурсы оставались с запасом.

Для nodejs нашел, что данный параметр можно регулировать через переменную --max_old_space_size=

Пробовал передавать несколькими способами, но результат вообще не меняется.

Подскаджите, как правильно передать этот параметр?

Answer (score 0):

Помогли следующие действия:

В Dockerfile был внесен следующий параметр

ENV TOOL_NODE_FLAGS --max-old-space-size=4096

После чего процесс сборки завершился успешно.